# Additional page property fields in TYPO3 CMS 6.2

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

What would be the recommended method to add custom page property fields in TYPO3 6.2?
In 4.5 I used TemplaVoila which had its own page module and made it easy to add data records on a page level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several approaches:

1. The "vanilla" approach:

Create an extension (and with it the file `ext_emconf.php`) and then create a file `ext_tables.sql` in the extension root. In it you can put SQL-definitions for the new fields, by defining a `CREATE TABLE` statement for the pages table:

```
CREATE TABLE pages(
    myNewField int(11) DEFAULT '',
);
```

This SQL-definition will be merged with existing definitions for the table `page`.

Then you need to configure the new field in the [Table Configuration Array (TCA)](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Index.html). You can usually find good examples in existing extensions, for example in `realurl`. There are two places where you can put these definitions, either in the file `ext_tables.php` (uncached), or into a php file in the folder `Configuration/Tca/Overrides` (cached).

This approach sounds like more work than it actually is.

2. Just use TemplaVoila. It is available for TYPO3 6.2, but its future is uncertain, AFAIK.
3. Use the [fluidtypo3](http://fluidtypo3.org/)-Ecosystem of extensions, and especially the extension `fluidpages`. It does what you want, in a similar way to TemplaVoila, but with modern (= fluid-based) technologies.

Answer (score 2):

if you need your own custom content elements, i recommend the extension "DCE" (Dynamic Content Elements).

DCE is really easy to customise and you can create Content elements in some minutes.

---

Also you can do it like Jost said. Do it with an own extension and put the TCA definition in your extTables.php

As example:

*/www/htdocs/website/typo3conf/ext/custom_extension/ext_tables.php*

```
$tmp_itm_extended_columns_pages = array(
    'link_class' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:itm_extended/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:label.linkClass',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'items' => array(
                array('Nichts', ''),
                array('Zahnrad', 'icon-afford', 'EXT:custom_extension/Resources/Public/img/icons/icon_preferences_small.png'),
                array('Fabrik', 'icon-factory', 'EXT:custom_extension/Resources/Public/img/icons/icon_factory_small.png'),
                array('Computer', 'icon-software', 'EXT:custom_extension/Resources/Public/img/icons/icon_software_small.png'),
                array('Person', 'icon-jobs', 'EXT:custom_extension/Resources/Public/img/icons/icon_person_small.png'),
                array('Welt', 'icon-world', 'EXT:custom_extension/Resources/Public/img/icons/icon_world_small.png'),
                array('Rohre', 'icon-pipe', 'EXT:custom_extension/Resources/Public/img/icons/icon_pipe_small.png'),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

*Then you have to add your new field to the ext_tables.sql*

```
#
# Table structure for table 'pages'
#
CREATE TABLE pages (

    link_class text

);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I was aware of DCE but my problem is page level configuration. Upvoted your answer anyway for the TCA and SQL samples that add nicely to the answer of Jost.