# Add custom page configuration field in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

Please help,

I created an extension with the [Builder Extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/builder).
In the extension I included a simple fluid page template.

Then I added a custom page setup field as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26144587/4399702).

(1.add DB-Field in ext_tables.sql; 2. add TCA definition in extTables.php)

Unfortunately no field appears. I tried the proposed way (ext_tables.sql):

```
$tmp_itm_extended_columns_pages = array(
    'customTemplateClass' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,.....
```

as well as the version from realurl:

```
$TCA['pages']['columns'] += array(
    'customTemplateClass' => array(
        'label' => 'customTemplateClass'...
```

Don't know how to get that custom page setup running.
Is there a problem combinig it with fluid page templates?

Thanks for help
Mathias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add custom text field for page configuration within an extension.
Here is how I implemented a custom field within my fluid template extension, ready for page level sliding:

1.)
Define custom text field:
myExt/ext_tables.php

```
$TCA['pages']['columns'] += array(
    'customTemplateClass' => array(
        'label' => 'Custom Template Class',
        'exclude' => 1,
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'input',
            'max' => 255,
            'eval' => 'trim,nospace,lower'
        ),
    ),
);
```

2.)
Add the field to the TCA type configuration:
myExt/ext_tables.php

```
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes (
    'pages',
    'customTemplateClass'
);
```

3.)
Write custom field to database:
myExt/ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE pages (
    customTemplateClass varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);
```

4.)
Add custom field to rootlinefields for page level sliding:
myExt/ext_localconf.php

```
$rootlinefields = &$GLOBALS["TYPO3_CONF_VARS"]["FE"]["addRootLineFields"];
if($rootlinefields != '')
{
    $rootlinefields .= ' , ';
}
$rootlinefields .= 'customTemplateClass';
```

5.)
Get the custom class of current page or if empty of the parent page:
TypoScript:

```
lib.pageconfig {
    customTemplateClass = TEXT
    customTemplateClass {
        value = default
        override {
           required = 1
           data = levelfield : -1 , customTemplateClass, slide  
        }
    }
}
```

6.)
Output in Fluid-Template file:

```
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.pageconfig.customTemplateClass')}
```

Comment: Some sugestions for TYPO3 7 are to use ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns (instead of +=) and use Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php instead of ext_tables.php. Official example (but without sliding): https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html

Comment: I have the same problem on a Typo3 v8.7 version, would be same steps ? 
what should i use to add a custom field for pages with slide on subpages ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the field to the [TCA type configuration](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Types/Index.html) for the table "pages" where it should show up. There is a [utility method](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_management_utility.html#aba12675080ad9c2ba1321947349c5ca3) for adding it to all configured types.

Comment: Great, this works perfect.
See next answer for whole explanation, how I did it.